# Jupyter Notebook Cannot Connect to Kernel, Likely due to Zipline / AssertionError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, apple-m1, zipline

All of my virtual environments work fine, except for one in which the jupyter notebook won't connect for kernel. This environment has Zipline in it, so I expect there is some dependency that is a problem there, even though I installed all packages with Conda.

I've read the question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54955563/jupyter-notebook-cannot-connect-to-kernel), and unfortunately downgrading tornado to 5.1.1 didn't work nor do I get ValueErrors. I am, however, getting an AssertionError that appears related to the Class NSProcessInfo.

I'm on an M1 Mac. Log from terminal showing the error below, and my environment file is below that. Can someone help me get this kernel working? Thank you!

---

```
[I 08:11:54.738 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 01327890-c603-461c-b82d-90bc7fd196ae, name: conda-env-env_zipline-py
[W 08:11:54.832 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js (::1) 5.650000ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/10-Quantopian-Platform/BSM%20Quantopian-Zipline%20Notes.ipynb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-121>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 582, in initialize
    self.init_kernel()
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 452, in init_kernel
    user_ns=self.user_ns,
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 86, in __init__
    appnope.nope()
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 90, in nope
    "Because Reasons"
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 60, in beginActivityWithOptions
    NSProcessInfo = C('NSProcessInfo')
  File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appnope/_nope.py", line 38, in C
    assert ret is not None, "Couldn't find Class %s" % classname
AssertionError: Couldn't find Class NSProcessInfo
```

---

```
# packages in environment at /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alembic                   1.5.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.2            py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py36h20b66c6_2    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bcolz                     1.2.1           py36h4f17bb1_1001    conda-forge
bleach                    3.3.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
blosc                     1.19.0               h4a8c4bd_0    conda-forge
bokeh                     2.3.0            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.2            py36h809c706_3    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py36h20b66c6_1001    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hc929b4f_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.1.19            hecd8cb5_1  
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py36hecd8cb5_0  
cffi                      1.14.5           py36hfaecaff_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
click                     7.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
contextvars               2.4                        py_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py36h3d45be8_0    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py36h20b66c6_3    conda-forge
dask                      2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2.10.1                     py_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
distributed               2.30.1           py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
empyrical                 0.5.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h4cff582_1    conda-forge
fsspec                    0.8.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
greenlet                  0.4.16           py36h37b9a7d_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.1.0           nompi_py36h9252a2b_100    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h3e39495_100    conda-forge
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
immutables                0.15             py36h49ba835_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        3.9.1            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py36h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython                   5.8.0                    py36_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
iso3166                   1.0.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
iso4217                   1.6.20180829               py_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   hbcb3906_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.11                 h11f7e16_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                8_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                8_openblas    conda-forge
libcxx                    10.0.0                        1  
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2  
libgfortran               4.0.0           7_5_0_h1a10cd1_21    conda-forge
libgfortran4              7.5.0               h1a10cd1_21    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                8_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.12          openmp_h63d9170_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7cec526_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               hbcb3906_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.1.0                ha78913b_3    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               11.1.0               hda6cdc1_0    conda-forge
locket                    0.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
logbook                   1.5.3            py36h20b66c6_4    conda-forge
lru-dict                  1.1.6            py36h20b66c6_3    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.2                h4a8c4bd_1    conda-forge
mako                      1.1.4              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36h20b66c6_3    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py36h20b66c6_1003    conda-forge
mock                      4.0.3            py36h79c6626_1    conda-forge
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py36h863e41a_1    conda-forge
multipledispatch          0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
nb_conda                  2.2.1                    py36_0  
nb_conda_kernels          2.3.1            py36hecd8cb5_0  
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.0.7            py36h79c6626_3    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h0a44026_1  
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  1.11                     py36_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.3.0            py36hecd8cb5_0  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py36hcc1bba6_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.19.5           py36h08dc641_1    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h9ed2024_0  
packaging                 20.9               pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.22.0                   py36_1    conda-forge
pandas-datareader         0.6.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.13                 h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    8.1.0            py36hc04f27d_1    conda-forge
pip                       21.0.1           py36hecd8cb5_0  
prometheus_client         0.9.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                     py_1    conda-forge
psutil                    5.8.0            py36h20b66c6_1    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py36h20b66c6_2    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py36h79c6626_3    conda-forge
pytables                  3.6.1            py36hce38db3_2    conda-forge
python                    3.6.13               h88f2d9e_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python-editor             1.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
python-interface          1.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.6                     1_cp36m    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py36h20b66c6_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     20.0.0           py36h23ab428_1  
readline                  8.1                  h9ed2024_0  
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
requests-file             1.5.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
requests-ftp              0.3.1                      py_1    conda-forge
scipy                     1.5.1            py36h1dac7e4_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                52.0.0           py36hecd8cb5_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                      py_1    conda-forge
six                       1.15.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.4.3            py36hfa26744_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.35.2               hce871da_0  
statsmodels               0.11.1           py36h37b9a7d_2    conda-forge
tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.9.4            py36h79c6626_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hb0a8c7a_0  
toolz                     0.11.1                     py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   5.1.1            py36h1de35cc_0  
trading-calendars         2.1.1              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.3            py36h9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h1de35cc_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h23ab428_0  
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zipline                   1.4.1            py36haf1e3a3_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.4.5                h0384e3a_1    conda-forge
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9410

Comment: I hadn't seen that thread. After digging through it, it is helpful but not enough to solve: the solutions listed there involve updating python, but if I do that it's no longer compatible with zipline. Thank you, and other thoughts?

Comment: I found in another question that they suggest to reinstall `jupyterlab` with `pip` instead of `conda`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65197613/assertionerror-couldnt-find-class-nsprocessinfo

Comment: Just tried that. Also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

**What works:**

```
# Create environment
conda create -n zipline_env python=3.6 ipykernel

# Activate environment, make sure you can see it in jupyter notebooks
conda activate zipline_env
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=zipline_env

# Install Zipline
conda install -c conda-forge zipline
```

After that is complete, you can then conda install other packages, like  jupyter,  matplotlib, etc and the dependencies all worked fine for me.

**Why:**

- Zipline needs python 3.6 to run locally, so environment needs to be set up with python 3.6.
- To see the environment in Jupyter Notebook, I had also been installing nb_conda, that is likely where the problems were. By only installing ipykernel when creating the environment, then using the command line ipykernel command above to make it visible in jupyter notebook, I could then avoid nb_conda.